# Varieties connected by curves in projective spaces of small dimension

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves, projective-geometry, intersection-theory, projective-varieties

Let $X\subset\mathbb{P}^N$ be an irreducible complex variety. Fix an integer $a\geq 2$ and call $P_a$ the following property: given $x_1,\dots,x_a\in X$ general points there exists an irreducible curve $C\subset X$ such that $x_1,\dots,x_a\in C$, $C$ spans a projective space of dimension $2a-1$ and $\deg(C) > 2a-1$.

For instance, $P_2$ means that two general points of $X$ can be connected by a curve of degree at least $4$ lying in $\mathbb{P}^3$.

I would like to ask whether there is some natural condition one could put on $X$ (especially when $X$ is rational) for $P_a$ to hold?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome new contributor.  In my work with de Jong on rational simple connectedness of complete intersections, we studied the property that $a$ general points are contained in a curve of degree $a$ spanning an $a$-dimensional linear space.  If you choose two finite subsets $A'$ and $A''$ of $X$ of sizes $a'$ and $a''$ with $a'+a''=2a$, whose intersection is a singleton, and whose union contains the $a$ specified points, then the corresponding curves $C'$ and $C''$ have a union $C$ of degree $2a$ that spans a linear space of dimension $2a-1$.  You can probably deform $C$ to an irreducible curve.

Comment: Thank you. It seems to me that $C$ span a linear space of dimension $2a$. For the span of $C$ to have dimension $2a-1$ the curves $C'$ and $C''$ must intersect in two points.

Comment: In terms of rational connectedness I could rephrase my question as follows: say that $X\subset\mathbb{P}^N$ is rationally conncted and that through $a$ points of $X$ there is a rational curve of degree $2a$. Then one (or at least I) would expect this rational curve to span a $\mathbb{P}^{2a}$. Is there a class of rationally connected varieties for which this curve spans a $\mathbb{P}^{2a-1}$ instead?

Comment: You are correct: the intersection set should be at least two points.

Comment: For simplicity, let me assume that the Mori cone of $X$ is generated by the class $\beta$ of a line. The "expected dimension" of the parameter space of rational curves of degree $2a$ that contain $a$ points is then  $a(2\langle c_1(T_X),\beta \rangle +1 - \text{dim}(X)) + \text{dim}(X)-3$.  On the other hand, the "expected codimension" of the locus of "linearly degenerate" rational curves of degree $2a$ equals $N+1-2a$.  So if $a(2\langle c_1(T_X),\beta \rangle +3-\text{dim}(X))$ is at least as large as $N+4-\text{dim}(X)$, then we expect such curves to exist.

Comment: . . . So, if $X$ is a hypersurface of degree $d$, then we expect such curves to exist, roughly if $d$ is no greater than $(N+3)/2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am writing an answer to the question in the comments. Let $a$ be a positive integer.  Let $X\subset \mathbb{P}^N$ be a linearly nondegenerate, smooth, projective variety.  Let $\alpha \in \text{Hom}(\text{Pic}(X)/\text{Pic}^0(X),\mathbb{Z})$ be the class of a rational curve in $X$.  Denote by $a$ the $\mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}^N}(1)|_X$-degree of $\alpha$.  Assume that for $a$ general points of $X$ there exists an irreducible curve of degree $\alpha$ in $X$ that contains those points.  This implies the inequality, $$\langle c_1(T_X),\alpha \rangle \geq a(\text{dim}(X)-1) - (\text{dim}(X)-3).$$  For smooth complete intersections in $\mathbb{P}^N$ of type $(d_1,\dots,d_c)$, this is equivalent to the inequality, $$\frac{N-3-c}{a} + c+2 \geq d_1 + \dots + d_c,$$ and this inequality is also sufficient if the characteristic is $0$ and the complete intersection is general in moduli.

Inside the space of irreducible, genus-$0$ stable maps of class $2\alpha$ containing $a$ general points, consider the locus of those whose linear span has dimension at most $2a-1$.  By the usual theory of the Thom-Porteous formula, the codimension of every irreducible component of this locus is at most $N+1-2a$.  On the other hand, the locus of double covers of curves of class $\alpha$ is in this locus and has codimension $\langle c_1(T_X),\alpha \rangle - 2$.  Thus, whenever the following inequality holds, $$\langle c_1(T_X),\alpha \rangle \geq N+3-2a,$$ then the double covers deform / generize to irreducible, genus-$0$ stable maps that are not double covers (hence are birational to their image) and whose linear span has dimension at most $2a-1$.

In particular, if $X$ is a smooth, complete intersection in $\mathbb{P}^N$ of type $(d_1,\dots,d_c)$, the inequality above holds if $$a(N+3-(d_1+\dots+d_c)) \geq N+3.$$  For $a=1$, of course this is correct: linearly degenerate "conics" must be double covers of lines.  For $a=2$, this recovers the inequality in the comments: $d_1+\dots+d_c$ is no greater than $(N+3)/2$.

Comment: Thank you. If I got it right in your answer (also in the second part) you are assuming that through $a$ general points of $X$ there is a curve of degree $a$. Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, I am assuming that through $a$ general points there is an irreducible, genus-$0$ curve of degree $a$.  Under that assumption, and assuming the inequality $\langle c_1(T_X),\alpha \rangle \geq N+3-2a$, there are also irreducible, genus-$0$ curves of degree $2a$ (not multiple covers) that are linearly degenerate.